# Why the MVC controller action not receiving model object with correct values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I see my controller action gets the id parameter correctly. The URL is correct as it hits the action.

The model has all fields set to null even though I am sending fully populated model object from the js function.

WHY THE CONTROLLER IS NOT GETTING THE MODEL OBJECT WITH THE VALUES I AM PASSING?

JS Function that sends the request:

```
function updateSettings(){
        //read values from the form                
                var name = $name_from_page;
                var msg = $msg_from_page;
                var abt = $abt_from_page;
                var bg = $BG_from_page;

                var webLinks = [];
                var text = "";
                var url = "";
                for(var i=1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    text = $text_from_page;
                    url = $url_from_page;                             
                webLinks.push({ Text: text, URL: url });
                }      
            var allowLikes = $allowLikes_from_page;
                var allowComments = $allowComments_from_page;

                var model = {};
                model.Title = name;
                model.Message = msg;
                model.About = abt;
                model.BannerBGColor = bg;
                model.BannerBGImage = "";
                model.AllowComments = allowLikes;
                model.AllowLikes = allowComments;
                model.WebLinks = webLinks;

            //using js library to send request
                Requestor
                .post("Update_Page_URL")
                .addParams({ model: model })
                .send();
}
```

This is what is getting passed to controller action:

```
{"Title":"Bob","Message":"Message","About":"About Bob","BannerBGColor":"#eee;","BannerBGImage":"","AllowComments":true,"AllowLikes":false,"WebLinks":[{"Text":"abc","URL":"www.abc.com"}]}
```

Controlelr Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateSettings(string id, PageModel model)
{
  //read model and update database
  //model object has all fields null and the 2 booleans are false <<== ISSUE
}
```

The model used in the controller action:

```
public class PageModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public string About { get; set; }

        public string BannerBGColor { get; set; }

        public string BannerBGImage { get; set; }

        public bool AllowComments { get; set; }

        public bool AllowLikes { get; set; }

        public List<WebLink> WebLinks { get; set; }        

    }
```

Comment: See this question, which looks similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110482/asp-net-mvc-3-posting-complex-json-model-to-action

Comment: Looks closer...will be trying. Thx

Comment: I checked that out. My code is doing the same thing as suggested by Darrin in the solution. I tested the json I am passing. It is a valid json. But still my controller object has null values...

Comment: But you also have an id argument which may be confusing it. Try putting the id in the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action is expecting JSON but you also have a string id argument there. Move the id into the JSON and remember to set your content type:

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Comment: The issue was in the library I was using. Seems fixed now.